# Why do we need an external zookeeper for Solrcloud?

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I want to set up a solr cloud using 3 different machines. All the examples i came across are advising me to download zookeeper as well.

However Solr comes with an inbuilt Zookeeper. Why cannot we use that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now the embedded zookeeper is supposed to be mostly for testing/developing. Reasons being that it is less battle tested in production and that if Solr process goes down, zk goes down too, making the cluster less resilient than a separate  process.

That being said, there are some voices saying that setting up a separate zk ensemble is too troublesome, so maybe this changes in the future.

Comment: In addition you don't really need as many zookeepers as you have Solr servers usually, and it's far more transparent to admin a separate Zookeeper ensemble (i.e. monitoring, tweaking, re-using) than using the bundled version.